# Which materials we can use for storing liquid nitrogen?

Tags: materials, metallurgy, metals, liquid, cryogenics

What are the materials we can use for the long-term storage of 30~liters of liquid nitrogen with composition and grade, along with the thickness of the sheet and storage capacity? Can we use any composites for the same? And which is the best among all?

The nitrogen is for rocket cooling, but the device doesn't need to be a thermo-flask.

Please provide references also.

Comment: The answer to the question may depend on the amount of LIN to be stored & the reason for storing it: long term or short term storage. From 2 minutes searching the web I found LIN containers being made of borosilcate glass, aluminium, stainless steel. The thickness of the material used will also depend on whether a thermo-flask device or not. This question is not specific enough.

Comment: I want to store 30 lit of LIN, reason is for the cooling purpose in rockets, for long term storage. Thermo-flask device is costly and hard to manufacture so it is not feasible for our purpose.

Comment: Pertinent information should be added into the original question. But what sort of rockets? and is the nitrogen blown off after doing the cooling or recycled ?

Comment: Basically, you have two options: (1) use professionally designed and constructed storage containers, or (2) die in a very nasty accident. **Don't even consider building your own device for storing liquid N2**.

Comment: The thermoflask serves two purposes. First, it keeps it cold if you want it cold. You don't care about this. Second, it keeps it cold because otherwise it boils, the pressure becomes extreme, and most materials fail. This feature should be important to you. I will qualify alephzero's statement because I have friends who fit the caveat- _unless you are a PE qualified to work at a rocket design company_ don't even consider building your own device for storing liquid N2. If you're still not convinced, spend some time watching youtube videos of rockets exploding.

Comment: How long is long term? As you could make/buy an "open" dewar with a loose fitting lid reasonably easily. These are traditionally used for transporting, but if it's insulated enough then it can take days for it to all evaporate. In this case you do also have to make sure that the area you store it won't let the evaporated nitrogen build up as there may be a risk of asphyxiation (and obviously don't seal it inside another container).

Answer (score 1):

If you like living, do not attempt to build your own high-pressure LN2 tank if you have never designed commercial-grade pressure vessels before. [Use this](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/8121?SID=srch-srp-8121).